# Convert a spark DataFrame to pandas DF

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to convert a Spark Df (not RDD) to pandas DF

I tried the following:

```
var some_df = Seq(
 ("A", "no"),
 ("B", "yes"),
 ("B", "yes"),
 ("B", "no")

 ).toDF(
"user_id", "phone_number")
```

Code:

```
%pyspark
pandas_df = some_df.toPandas()
```

Error:

```
 NameError: name 'some_df' is not defined
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: You don't declare python variables using `var`

Comment: @user3483203 yep, I created the data frame in the note book with the Spark and Scala interpreter.  and used '%pyspark' while trying to convert the DF into pandas DF.

Comment: why are you mixing scala and pyspark. just use one

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Yep I use scala. But I am trying to build visualizations for the columns in the Spark DF, for which I couldn't find relevant sources.

Comment: what kind of visualizations?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan histogram, or any plots for finding the distribution of every column in the DF

Comment: check out http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/statistical-data-exploration-spark-part-2/

Comment: @RameshMaharjan thanks i will.

Comment: and yes pandas has a lot of features so you can switch to pyspark as scala spark is identical to pyspark but with pyspark you can combine with pandas

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Can you please help me on this? 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052866/max-in-window-functions'

Answer (score 99, accepted):

following should work

**Sample DataFrame**

```py
    some_df = sc.parallelize([
     ("A", "no"),
     ("B", "yes"),
     ("B", "yes"),
     ("B", "no")]
     ).toDF(["user_id", "phone_number"])
```

**Converting DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame**

```
    pandas_df = some_df.toPandas()
```

Comment: The `toDF(...)` of the answer is a red herring and should be removed for clarity, IMO. It's already present in the question. That is why I've updated the below answer instead.

Comment: what "sc" stands for in this case?

Comment: @Gabriel it's spark context

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have tried applying this to my code on pySpark 3.2.0 and I get an error, that a second parameter, `c` is now required for function `parallelize` based on <https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.parallelize.html>. Tried to add a constant `c` with 

```example_df = sc\
    .parallelize([ ("A", "no"), ("B", "yes"), ("B", "yes"), ("B", "no")], c=4)\
    .toDF( ["user_id", "phone_number"] )
```
to get another error:
```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'defaultParallelism'```

Answer (score 39):

In my case the following conversion from spark dataframe to pandas dataframe worked:

```
pandas_df = spark_df.select("*").toPandas()
```

Comment: there is no need to put `select("*")` on `df` unless you want some specific columns. This is not going to affect the performance as it's lazy execution and not gonna do anything.

Comment: For some reason, the solution from @Inna was the only one that worked on my dataframe. No conversion was possible except with selecting all columns beforehand. The data type was the same as usually, but I had previously applied a UDF.

Comment: I am using this but most of my spark decimal columns are converting to object in pandas instead of float. I have 100+ columns. Is there a way this type casting can be modified?

Comment: You can write a function and type cast it

Answer (score 15):

Converting spark data frame to pandas can take time if you have large data frame. So you can use something like below:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

pd_df = df_spark.toPandas()
```

I have tried this in DataBricks.

Comment: The ```spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled``` option is highly recommended, especially with ```pyspark.pandas``` in the upcoming spark 3.2 release.

Comment: The SQL config 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' has been deprecated in Spark v3.0 and may be removed in the future. Use 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' instead of it.

Comment: Can you please explain why it makes more efficient?