# max in window functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input DF:

```
id .  sub_id .   id_created .  id_last_modified   sub_id_created . lead_
1 .    10          12:00         7:00               12:00 .        1:00
1 .    20 .        12:00         7:00                1:00 .        2:30
1 .    30 .        12:00         7:00                2:30 .        7:00
1 .    40          12:00         7:05                7:00          null
```

Use case, I am trying to create a new_column "time", where:

```
1. For: (id, max(sub_id)) : id_last_modified - sub_id_created
2. otherwise:  sub_id_created - lead_
```

Code:

```
window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("sub_id")
```

I am getting the expected op for all the rows except for the combination of:

```
(id, max(sub_id))
```

for which I am getting null

Any suggestions on where am I going wrong will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: your tried code seems to be a mix of scala and pyspark

Comment: and how does unix_timestamp converts formats as 7:00 to valid timestamp? as you say its partially working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess this might work

```
df = df.withColumn("time",
when($"sub_id"===max($"sub_id").over(window), 
(unix_timestamp($"id_last_modified")- 
unix_timestamp($"sub_id_created"))/3600.0).otherwise( 
(unix_timestamp($"sub_id_created") - 
unix_timestamp(lead($"sub_id_created", 1).over(window)))/3600.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 31)
df = web.DataReader("goog", 'yahoo', start, end)
```