# How to convert scala spark.sql.dataFrame to Pandas data frame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I wanted to Convert scala dataframe into pandas data frame

```
    val collection = spark.read.sqlDB(config)
    collection.show()

    #Should be like df=collection
```

Comment: It would be easier if you use pyspark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958721/convert-a-spark-dataframe-to-pandas-df

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a way of using a Python library from Scala. This is a bit weird to me. Are you sure you have to do that? Maybe you know that, but Scala DataFrames have a good API that will probably give you the functionality you need from pandas.

If you still need to use pandas, I would suggest you to write the data that you need to a file (a csv, for example). Then, using a Python application you can load that file into a pandas dataframe and work from there.

Trying to create a pandas object from Scala is probably overcomplicating things (and I am not sure it is currently possible).

Answer (score 0):

I think If you want to use `pandas` based API in `SPARK` code, then you can install `Koalas-Python` library. So, Whatever the function you want to use from `pandas` API directly you can embed them in `SPARK` code.

To install kolas

```
pip install koalas
```

Comment: I think here ```collection``` variable is ```dataframe```.  ```toPandas()``` def would be there. If you apply the ```toPandas()``` function it will return pandas based data frame. This link will give more information about installing ```kolas``` and how to use It. https://medium.com/future-vision/databricks-koalas-python-pandas-for-spark-ce20fc8a7d08

Comment: Not related to my question.