# Calculate metrics with Lifetimes python package with Spark/Python [object has no attribute 'sort_values']

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, lifetimes-python

I am using Lifetimes python package in my spark cluster and trying to calculate some metrics -- [Lifetimes package](https://lifetimes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I have been using spark 2.4.2. I have data frame like  below sample (original data has 800K records) , containing 'invoce_date' column and some other columns (id, label, county etc)

```
# reproducible Spark 
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('78aa', 1, 'A', '2020-04-14 19:00:00'),
        ('14aa', 3, 'B', '2020-04-17 16:00:00'),
        ('25aa', 5, 'A', '2020-04-14 15:30:00'),
        ('36aa', 7, 'B', '2020-04-14 21:30:00')
    ],
    ('id', 'X', 'label', 'invoce_date')
)
```

Here I am trying to leverage Lifetimes

```
import lifetimes

# set the last transaction date as the end point for this historical dataset


current_date = df.agg(max("invoce_date")).collect()[0][0]



# calculate the metrics
metrics = (
  lifetimes.utils.summary_data_from_transaction_data(
    df,
    customer_id_col='id',
    datetime_col='invoce_date',
    observation_period_end = current_date, 
    freq='D'
    )
  )

# display first few rows
metrics.head(10)
```

This return an error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'` , I have added  `df = df.sort("invoce_date")`before metric calculation but still keep getting the same error and I couldn't figure it out

Here is my datatype for reference

```
df.dtypes
[('id', 'string'),
 ('y', 'string'),
 ('label', 'string'),
 ('invoce_date', 'timestamp')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lifetimes uses *Pandas* dataframes, while the `df` variable in your example is a *PySpark* dataframe. Before using functions from the Lifetimes package you have to convert your data into a Pandas dataframe by calling `df.toPandas()` (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959213/2129801)).

Please note that calling `toPandas()` will [load](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas) all data into the driver's memory. Lifetimes does not support distributed computing with multiple executors.